# How to get numbers from a string and add them?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find a number from a string and return the value.

If a string contains more than one number then it should add all the numbers in string and return the total.

For Ex: "20 min was spent on team huddle meeting and 90 minutes were spend on training" So the return value should be 110 (90+20)

Comment: look into using RegEx

Comment: What have you tried? Have you googled - this is not an uncommon question?

Comment: are the numbers always in the same position? Same number of characters? One way or another, worksheet text functions can do this. (ie., FIND,MID, LEN, etc)

Comment: Yes I googled it, but not able to identify which code will work for me. Because I do not understand their solution. @ SJR

Comment: @Banana I don't know how to use regex. It would  be great if you can help

Comment: @ashleedawg No numbers are not always at the same position.

Comment: @PalashGangal the answers and/or examples are only meant to assist you overcome your difficulties, and not to function as a black box that you can use 'as is' because you dont understand how it works. if your understanding in coding is not sufficient to understand the solutions you found online, then first i recommend you learn some more coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Public Function NumEx(s As String) As Double
    Dim L As Long, i As Long, s2 As String
    Dim CH As String

    L = Len(s)
    NumEx = 0
    If L = 0 Then Exit Function
    s2 = ""

    For i = 1 To L
        CH = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[0-9]" Or CH = "." Then
            s2 = s2 & CH
        Else
            s2 = s2 & " "
        End If
    Next i

    s2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(s2)
    arry = Split(s2, " ")

    For Each a In arry
        NumEx = NumEx + a
    Next a
End Function
```

[image]

**NOTE:**

- the input string is converted into an array of numbers
- the array is then summed

**EDIT#1:**

A VBA UDF can be use in two ways:

1. in a cell *(see the picture above)*
2. from a **Sub** or from another UDF

Here is an example of the second way:

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me how to run a function program in VBA, I am working in normal module, and if I paste this program it asks me to name the macro, and it creates a new sub and end sub.

Comment: @PalashGangal  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Thanks a lot, now I am able to run the code. But its returning value in msg box and not as you have shown in your excel screenshot. And which line in your code is deciding that it has to pick string from which column,

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot for your help. Wish I could code like this.

Comment: can this take the string from different sheet in same workbook? because its giving #value if I try to use it by giving reference to cell in different sheet.

Comment: @PalashGangal  We are almost there!  The first picture shows how to use the function in a worksheet cell *(like you would use Vlookup)*.  The second picture shows how to use the function from a sub.

Comment: @PalashGangalTo use a cell in a different worksheet try **=numex('new data'!C3)** or something like it

Answer (score 4):

Try [regex](/questions/tagged/regex).

```
Option Explicit

Function sumNums(str As String) As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Static rgx As Object, cmat As Object

    If rgx Is Nothing Then
        Set rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    End If

    With rgx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = "[0-9]{1,7}"
        If .test(str) Then
            Set cmat = .Execute(str)
            For n = 0 To cmat.Count - 1
                sumNums = sumNums + cmat.Item(n)
            Next n
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Using a static object is a great idea *(+1)*